# Finding average using reduce and collect

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to understand the new Java 8 Stream APIs.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html

I found the example of finding average of numbers using collect API. But I felt that, the same can be done using reduce() also.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Using collect
        System.out.println(Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
            .collect(Averager::new, Averager::accept, Averager::combine)
            .average());

        // Using reduce
        System.out.println(Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
            .reduce(new Averager(), (t, u) -> {
                t.accept(u);
                return t;
            }, (t, u) -> {
                t.combine(u);
                return t;
            }).average());
    }

    private static class Averager {
        private int total = 0;
        private int count = 0;

        public Averager() {
            // System.out.println("Creating averager");
        }

        public double average() {
            // System.out.println("Finding average");
            return count > 0 ? ((double) total) / count : 0;
        }

        public void accept(int i) {
            // System.out.println("Accepting " + i);
            total += i;
            count++;
        }

        public void combine(Averager other) {
            // System.out.println("Combining the averager : " + other);
            total += other.total;
            count += other.count;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "[total : " + total + ", count: " + count + "]";
        }
    }
}
```

1) Is there any reason, that I should use collect instead of reduce here?
2) If I enable all the debug sysouts, I can see that the operations perfomed are exactly the same between, collect and reduce. And the combiner was not being used at all, in both cases.
3) If I make the streams parallel, the collect is always returning me correct result. The reduce() is giving me different results each time.
4) Should I not use reduce, in parallel streams?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The difference between `reduce` and `collect` is that `collect` is an enhanced form of reduction that can deal with mutable objects in parallel. The `collect` algorithm thread-confines the various result objects, so that they can be mutated safely, even if they aren't thread-safe. That's why `Averager` works using `collect`. For sequential computation using `reduce` this doesn't usually matter, but for parallel computation it will give incorrect results, as you observed.

A key point is that `reduce` works as long as it is dealing with **values** but not mutable objects. You can see this by looking at the first argument to `reduce`. The example code passes `new Averager()` which is a **single object** that's used as the identity value by multiple threads in the parallel reduction. The way parallel streams work is that the workload is split into segments that are processed by individual threads. If multiple threads are mutating the same (non-thread-safe) object, it should be clear why this will lead to incorrect results.

It is possible to use `reduce` to compute an average, but you need to make your accumulation object be immutable. Consider an object `ImmutableAverager`:

```
static class ImmutableAverager {
    private final int total;
    private final int count;

    public ImmutableAverager() {
        this.total = 0;
        this.count = 0;
    }
    
    public ImmutableAverager(int total, int count) {
        this.total = total;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public double average() {
        return count > 0 ? ((double) total) / count : 0;
    }

    public ImmutableAverager accept(int i) {
        return new ImmutableAverager(total + i, count + 1);
    }

    public ImmutableAverager combine(ImmutableAverager other) {
        return new ImmutableAverager(total + other.total, count + other.count);
    }
}
```

Note that I've adjusted the signatures of `accept` and `combine` to return a new `ImmutableAverager` instead of mutating `this`. (These changes also make the methods match the function arguments to `reduce` so we can use method references.) You'd use `ImmutableAverager` like this:

```
    double average = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
            .parallel()
            .reduce(new ImmutableAverager(), 
                    ImmutableAverager::accept,
                    ImmutableAverager::combine)
            .average();
    System.out.println("Average: "+average);
```

Using immutable value objects with `reduce` should give the correct results in parallel.

Finally, note that `IntStream` and `DoubleStream` have `summaryStatistics()` methods and `Collectors` has `averagingDouble`, `averagingInt`, and `averagingLong` methods that can do these computations for you. However, I think the question is more about the mechanics of collection and reduction than about how to do averaging most concisely.

Comment: Thanks you for such a detailed answer.

Comment: One small correction: collection is not actually a specialization of reduction, it's the other way round. Any reduction can be expressed as a collection, whereas there's no general way of expressing a collection as a reduction (or at least no way without forcing client code to manage concurrency). So in fact reduction is a specialized form of collection.