# What is the Java 8 reduce BinaryOperator used for?

Tags: java, java-8, binary-operators

I am currently reading the O'Reilly **Java 8 Lambdas**, it is a really good book. I came across with a example like this.

I have a

```
private final BiFunction<StringBuilder,String,StringBuilder>accumulator=
(builder,name)->{if(builder.length()>0)builder.append(",");builder.append("Mister:").append(name);return builder;};

final Stream<String>stringStream = Stream.of("John Lennon","Paul Mccartney"
,"George Harrison","Ringo Starr");
final StringBuilder reduce = stringStream
    .filter(a->a!=null)
    .reduce(new StringBuilder(),accumulator,(left,right)->left.append(right));
 System.out.println(reduce);
 System.out.println(reduce.length());
```

this produce the right output.

`Mister:John Lennon,Mister:Paul Mccartney,Mister:George Harrison,Mister:Ringo Starr`

My question is regarding the `reduce` method the last parameter which is a `BinaryOperator`.

Which this parameter is used for? If I change by

```
.reduce(new StringBuilder(),accumulator,(left,right)->new StringBuilder());
```

the output is the same; if I pass `NULL` then N.P.E is returned.

What is this parameter used for?

### Update

Why if I run it on `parallelStream` I am receiving different results?

First run:

```
returned StringBuilder length = 420
```

Second run:

```
returned StringBuilder length = 546
```

Third run:

```
returned StringBuilder length = 348
```

and so on. Why is this - should it not return all the values at each iteration?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The method `reduce` in the interface `Stream` is overloaded. The parameters for the method with three arguments are:

- identity
- accumulator
- combiner

The `combiner` supports parallel execution. Apparently, it is not used for *sequential streams*. However, there is no such guarantee. If you change your *streams* into *parallel stream*, I guess you will see a difference:

```
Stream<String>stringStream = Stream.of(
    "John Lennon", "Paul Mccartney", "George Harrison", "Ringo Starr")
    .parallel();
```

Here is an example of how the `combiner` can be used to transform a sequential reduction into a reduction, that supports parallel execution. There is a stream with four `String`s and `acc` is used as an abbreviation for `accumulator.apply`. Then the result of the reduction can be computed as follows:

```
acc(acc(acc(acc(identity, "one"), "two"), "three"), "four");
```

With a compatible `combiner`, the above expression can be transformed into the following expression. Now it is possible to execute the two sub-expressions in different threads.

```
combiner.apply(
    acc(acc(identity, "one"), "two"),
    acc(acc(identity, "three"), "four"));
```

---

Regarding your second question, I use a simplified `accumulator` to explain the problem:

```
BiFunction<StringBuilder,String,StringBuilder> accumulator =
    (builder,name) -> builder.append(name);
```

According to the Javadoc for [Stream::reduce](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), the `accumulator` has to be [associative](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Associativity). In this case, that would imply, that the following two expressions return the same result:

```
acc(acc(acc(identity, "one"), "two"), "three")  
acc(acc(identity, "one"), acc(acc(identity, "two"), "three"))
```

That's not true for the above `accumulator`. The problem is, that you are mutating the object referenced by `identity`. That's a bad idea for the `reduce` operation. Here are two alternative implementations which should work:

```
// identity = ""
BiFunction<String,String,String> accumulator = String::concat;

// identity = null
BiFunction<StringBuilder,String,StringBuilder> accumulator =
    (builder,name) -> builder == null
        ? new StringBulder(name) : builder.append(name);
```

Comment: thanks nosid i have a question why i am receiving differents results on every iteration i guess is for the parallelization... why is that severals results using the name code?? please see my edited question.

Comment: @chiperortiz: I have updated my answer regarding your second question.    Does the example really originate from the book? In this case, the phrase _good book_ seems questionable.

Comment: in the book is a more complex example and the use only sequential stream.

Comment: i will use you BiFunction but should i use the same BinaryOperator?

Answer (score 3):

[nosid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23981026/1441122) got it mostly right (+1) but I wanted to amplify a particular point.

The `identity` parameter to `reduce` must be an identity **value**. It's ok if it's an object, but if it is, it should immutable. If the "identity" object is mutated, it's no longer an identity! For more discussion of this point, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23661052/1441122) to a related question.

It looks like this example originated from Example 5-19 of Richard Warburton, *Java 8 Lambdas*, O'Reilly 2014. If so, I shall have to have a word about this with the good Dr. Warburton.

Comment: Similarly, the BinaryOperator parameter to reduce must be *associative*.  Otherwise you will get gibberish results in parallel.

Comment: the example by Richard is used in a sequential stream not parallel stream Stuart thanks by your reply...

Comment: @chiperortiz Indeed the example is sequential, but it's improper for code to give correct results sequentially and incorrect results in parallel, especially in a book that's trying to explain this stuff. (Also, I suspect even the sequential code violates some restrictions, and it's just lucky that it happens to give the correct result.)