# How to find the average value of the stream using the "reduce" function in Java Stream API?

Tags: java, reduce, steam

I have :

```
Stream.of(120, 410, 85, 32, 314, 12)
```

I tried, but seems it not right:

```
Stream.of(120, 410, 85, 32, 314, 12).reduce((a, b) -> b * b / a);
```

Comment: Duplicate question. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23661052/10343888).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an easier way to solve it:

```
double average = IntStream.of(120, 410, 85, 32, 314, 12)
    .average()
    .getAsDouble();

System.out.println(average);
```

Output:

> 162.16666666666666